# How to boot PC after BitLocker is half-enabled?

Tags: windows-10, boot, bitlocker

Long story short...I enabled BitLocker with group policy on a new batch of laptops as a test. After rebooting a couple of the laptops I figured out that I had conflicting settings for the "Require additional authentication at startup" GPO setting. This caused BitLocker to become "enabled" but it was in the "Waiting for activation" stage. The goal was to have a BitLocker PIN set on the laptops, but the PIN was never set. Those laptops now boot into Dell's pre-boot performance check and then want to download a recovery OS. It would seem Windows doesn't appear to exist anymore. Do I need to re-install Windows or is there a way to recover from this?

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling bitlocker

Boot into the Windows recovery environment or use a USB recovery disk to access the command prompt.

In the command prompt window, type: manage-bde c: -off then hit Enter

More information on the manage-bde tool
[Manage-BDE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/manage-bde)